# Using a cell in another file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to keep the content of a UITableView cell in a separate file as I do in Objective-c even in my TodayExtension Swift table in order to wire it to the storyboard. Yet when I try to do it, it complaints it cannot find the class of the cell; this is the function I use:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        println(indexPath)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
            TableViewConstants.cellIdentifier,
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TodayCell
        let entry = busCollection[indexPath.row]
        cell.bus=entry.bus
        cell.destination=entry.destination;
        return cell

}
```

todayCell is the class in another file it reports it cannot find:

```
import UIKit
class TodayCell: UITableViewCell {
     @IBOutlet var bus: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet var stopAddress: UILabel!
     @IBOutlet var destination: UILabel!
}
```

Importing the file, even if not needed according the the Swift documentation, moved the error in the import statement.

Comment: Are you using prototypes in storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I linked them to the todayCell properties.

Comment: can you write the error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: Xcode forgot to add the new TodayCell file to the list of compile sources when I added it to the project. Once I manually did it everything worked fine - I had a funny horror trip in a list of errors in the MKStoreManager library, but all of them went away upon returning to the last commit.

Answer (score 0):

**Programmatically:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.registerClass(todayCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "todayCell")
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("todayCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! todayCell

    // Setup

    return cell
}
```

This should do it.

**Storyboard:**
If you're using prototypes, then you just have to set the prototype class to `todayCell` and an identifier. This identifier is used when you're creating the cell in `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()`

[image: identifier]

[image: class]

Comment: That does not change much things given todayCell is what I cannot reach and this of course applies even on your registration method.

Comment: The first method is when it's done programmatically. I've updated the answer for when you're using the storyboard.

Comment: Of course I know it, I am programming UITableviews in Objective-c since more than 5 years... my problem is that the compiler does not find the todayCell class, not the object!

Comment: Yet I found a funny issue: the module for the storyboard main controller is: In_ArrivoHD while the one for the cell is inArrivoHD without the underscore. I have no cue where those modules were assigned.

Comment: Well, sorry for misunderstanding. Usually experienced programmers would capitalize class names so I'd mistaken you for inexperienced. Of course it's all just up to personal preferences. Just to make sure, you added the class `todayCell` as class for the prototype cells?

Comment: I capitalized it myself. As stated above the problems seems due to the different modules assigned to the two classes. Yet I tried to put all of the them the same but there seems to change nothing, and it seems not possible to assign the module directly to the Swift files.

Comment: In practice if I add it capitalized or uncapitalized it keeps on not finding it... I corrected my code sample to have the class Capitalized for a better style. And, of course, the class to be reported as missing in the two points where it is used is the capitalized one.